# C# Specific Properties

Tags: c#, properties

Can I do something like this:

```
Configs.Environment.Development;
```

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
Configs.Environment == "DEV";
```

I don't particularly care for the strings, but I don't know how to set "specific" properties or if it's possible.

Comment: What is `Configs.Environment.Development;` supposed to be/do? Could you clarify what you are actually trying to do? Are you looking for an enumeration of values?

Comment: I am just trying to determine and set the environment that the code is currently in.  Then if that environment is set, use different settings for different environments.  

There might be a better way to do this all together...

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of:

Configs.Environment = "DEV";
Configs.Environment = "TEST";

I would like to do:
Configs.Environment.Development;
Configs.Environment.Testing;

So they are no longer strings but specific properties of the Environment...?

Comment: Are you talking about a set of properties, or just one?  To indicate the environment?

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about enums?

```
public enum Environment
{
    Development,
    Test,
    Live
}


Configs.Environment = Environment.Development;
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the sort of thing that's better handled by a preprocessor directive:

```
#if debug
/* etc */
#elseif production
/* etc */
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish that by making `Environment` an enumeration or making `Development` a static readonly string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
 public static class Configs{
         public static class Environment{
              public static readonly string Development="DEV";
          }

  }
```

But you probably want ENUMS, and use a factory to set your constants.

Comment: @tehMick: Why would that be so?

Comment: because it sounds like he is "toggling" constants.  It doesn't look like he just wants a list of properties to access.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2006/10/27/const-vs-static-readonly.aspx

Comment: @dtb - the major reason is because if another project references the one with the `const`, then that project would have to be recompiled if the `const` value ever changed (since `const` values are substituted at compile time). `static readonly` members are evaluated at run-time so they don't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the setting to take effect at compile time only or at runtime?  Do you want your user to be able to select different settings after deployment?

If you want a compile time only setting, then a pre-processor directive is what you want.

If you want runtime settings, .NET has direct support for .config files and you can access the values in your code (and set them too) via the **Settings.Default** constructs.

VisualStudio has support for easily creating and maintaining these config files.